# How can I get 3 inputs to have the same combined height as the textarea next to them?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

What I'm trying to achieve is having the the 3 light green `input`s on the left be equally spaced vertically and also have the top of the topmost one aligned with the top of the `textarea` on the right and also have the bottom of the bottommost one be aligned with the bottom of that `textarea`. I know that's a mouthful, but it should be obvious from this pic, in which the `textarea` is slightly too tall, what I'm trying to do:

http://s13.postimg.org/kv1z0aenb/Capture.png

(Wish I could embed the pic, but I don't have enough reputation.)

I've messed around with pixels until I got it right in Chrome and Firefox, but then it wasn't the same in Internet Explorer. So I need a better way of going about this.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <input type="text" class="hide-after-sendoff" name="name" value="Your Name" />
        <input type="text" class="hide-after-sendoff" name="email" value="Your Email Address" />
        <input type="text" class="hide-after-sendoff" name="phone" value="Your Phone Number" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <textarea class="hide-after-sendoff" name="comments" rows="6" />' . $bigBoxTxt . '</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.contact-form input, .contact-form textarea {
    border: 0;
    color: #FFF;
    background: #AED270;
    padding: 0.5em;
    width: 100%;
}
.contact-form input + input {
    margin-top: 1em;
}
.contact-form textarea {
    max-width: 100%; 
    resize: none;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/k4uvt2a1/)**

Here's my logic:

Since the `textarea` has 6 `rows` and a `padding` of `0.5em`, its total height should  be

```
0.5em + 6em + 0.5em = 7em
```

Since the left `inputs` have a `padding` of `0.5em` the bottom 2 of have a `margin-top` of `1em`, their total height should be

```
0.5em + 1em + 0.5em + 1em + 0.5em + 1em + 0.5em + 1em = 7em
```

So they should  be equal. Right? Or how can I do this better?

Comment: Browsers will render this differently anyway... When I need to do something like this I'd create the elements then set a physical height on the textarea to match the 3 text inputs - which of course fails for responsiveness by the way

Answer (score 2):

A little jQuery might save the day:

```
textarea {
    height: 100%;
}

$('#textarea-wrap').height($('#inputs-wrap').outerHeight());
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/k4uvt2a1/4/)**

Tested in Chrome, IE11 and Edge.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could achieve this by adding some additional bootstrap classes.

Adding the form-control class to the inputs and wrapping them in a div with the form-group class.

Like this:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="hide-after-sendoff form-control" name="name" value="Your Name" />
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="hide-after-sendoff form-control" name="email" value="Your Email Address" />
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="hide-after-sendoff form-control" name="phone" value="Your Phone Number" />
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
   <textarea class="hide-after-sendoff form-control" name="comments" rows="6" />' . $bigBoxTxt . '</textarea>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/DTcHh/11348)

Cleaned up jsFiddle link courtesy of @isherwood

If you resize the output window you can see how they stack/unstack.

Comment: Looks perfect in Chrome, but still screwed up in IE for me